# Gravity Forms ExactTarget Add-on Plugin: Nothing happens after step 2 when creating a new feed

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

This looks like a great plugin. When creating a new feed, I check the appropriate ExactTarget list(s) in Step 1. Step 2 appears prompting me to select a Gravity Form, but when I choose a form nothing else happens.

My browser inspector was showing the AJAX request to .../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php with a status of 200, but its response content was this:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in /.../wp-includes/functions.php:1038
Stack trace:
#0 /.../wp-includes/functions.php(1038): serialize(Array)
#1 /.../wp-includes/functions.php(615): maybe_serialize(Array) 
#2 /.../wp-includes/functions.php(805): add_option('_transient_extr...', Array, '', 'no')
#3 /.../wp-content/plugins/gravity-forms-exacttarget/api/ExactTarget.class.php(237): set_transient('extr_attributes', Array, 86400)
#4 /.../wp-content/plugins/gravity-forms-exacttarget/exacttarget.php(1018): ExactTarget->Attributes()
#5 [internal function]: GFExactTarget::select_exacttarget_form('')
#6 /.../wp-includes/plugin.php(405): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /.../http in <b>/.../wp-includes/functions.php</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there are some SimpleXMLElement objects in the array that is to be serialized in stack trace above, and as the error says, 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed.' Boo.

I tried to figure out how to modify the response so it replaces all the SimpleXMLElement objects, but this was a pain. I ended up commenting out line 237 of ExactTarget#Attributes() in /gravity-forms-exacttarget/api/ExactTarget.class.php:

```
// set_transient('extr_attributes', $attrs, 60*60*24);
return $attrs;
```

I'm not sure why the $attrs need to be stored as a transient. Things seemed to work fine without it being done.

Anyway, this seems to work for me. Any other suggestions?